# Kendo grid should show value from linked table

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a very simple product that has an editor from a user table.

The whole thing is mapped in the edmx.

In my fetch method I have some code:

```
    public ActionResult Products_Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        using (var context = new ProductModel())
        {
            var products = from row in context.Products select new { row.Id, row.Title, row.EditorId, row.Editor.Name };
            var result = products.ToDataSourceResult(request);
            //Debug:
            //var s = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet));
            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

Unfortunatly I can see that the Editor.Name gets serialized into "Name".

On the cshtml I then have my grid

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Product>()
      .Name("grid")
      .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
          .Ajax()
          .Model(model => model.Id(c => c.Id))
          .Read(read => read.Action("Products_Read", "Product"))
          .Update(update => update.Action("Products_Update", "Product"))
      )
      .Columns(product =>
      {
          product.Bound(p => p.Id).Hidden(true);
          product.Bound(p => p.Title).Title("Title");
          product.Template(p => p.Editor.Name).Title("Editor");//<-- HERE
```

Nothing comes in the grid and I assume I have to decorate something so the grid knows where to fetch the values.

Else I could do a viewmodel, but then I would loose a lot of the build in functionality.

Next step will be to get a dropdown when I edit the product. My hope is someone simply can give a link to a place where this is done out of the box.

Comment: What happens when you try this for your retrieve:
`var products = context.Products.ToList();`.  I know this will probably retrieve more than you want, but I believe the issue is with your `new { }` statement

Comment: ToList works. To give it as example the first part of the Json looks like this: ###{"ContentEncoding":null,"ContentType":null,"Data":{"Data":[
{"Id":1,"Title":"Book1","EditorId":218,"Name":"Bob"}### Notice how the name Bob is kind of annoying. In old times .Net there would be something indicating this was in a nested entity. I cannot do a context.Products.ToList because it would be too much, and I have to reduce the select because else I get a loop in the serialization

Answer (score 1):

You need to set template like this

```
.Columns(product =>
  {
      product.Bound(p => p.Editor.Name).Template(@<text>
           <strong>@item.Name</strong>
      </text>).Title("Editor");
  })
```

[Refrence](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/faq)

Comment: The @item.Name does not work since my product does not have a name. I think a viewmodel may be the easiest then.